# Selenium Webdriver Java test does not start in Jenkins. It works well from the command line (cmd)

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, testing, webdriver

I understand that it is not possible to get data from the resources.
Permission in services for interacting with the desktop in services is given.

simple tests pass:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnfRM.jpg)

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jLej.jpg)

---

### [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNgTz.jpg)

### [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxFfG.jpg)

---

---

### [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUPW0.jpg)

### [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVm81.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQktE.jpg)

---

In Jenkins I crawl the parameterized assembly line:

```
-Dbrowser=${browser} -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=${surefire.suiteXmlFiles} -Denvironment=${environment} clean test
```

---

error code

---

```
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at service.InstanceCreator.getDataEstimateForm(InstanceCreator.java:24)
at test.GoogleCloudTest.checkEmailEstimateCost(GoogleCloudTest.java:17)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.ResourceBundle$CacheKey.calculateHashCode(ResourceBundle.java:654)
at java.util.ResourceBundle$CacheKey.<init>(ResourceBundle.java:584)
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1333)
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:782)
at service.TestDataReader.<clinit>(TestDataReader.java:6)
... 35 more
```

... Removed 32 stack frames

---

### class for reading keys

```
public class TestDataReader {
private static final ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(System.getProperty("environment"));

public static String getTestData(String key) {
    return resourceBundle.getString(key);
}
```

}

---

### service class

```
public class InstanceCreator {
private static final String NUMBER_OF_INSTANCES = "testdata.instanceCreator.number";
private static final String OPERATION_SYSTEM = "testdata.instanceCreator.os";
private static final String MACHINE_CLASS = "testdata.instanceCreator.machine-class";
private static final String SERIES_ID = "testdata.instanceCreator.series-id";
private static final String MACHINE_TYPE = "testdata.instanceCreator.machine-type";
private static final String NUMBER_OF_GPUS = "testdata.instanceCreator.number-of-gpus";
private static final String TYPE_GPU = "testdata.instanceCreator.type-gpu";
private static final String LOCAL_SSD = "testdata.instanceCreator.local-ssd";
private static final String DATA_CENTER_LOCATION = "testdata.instanceCreator.datacenter";
private static final String COMMITTED_USAGE = "testdata.instanceCreator.committed-sage";

public static InstanceForm getDataEstimateForm() {
  return new InstanceForm(       
          TestDataReader.getTestData(NUMBER_OF_INSTANCES),
          TestDataReader.getTestData(OPERATION_SYSTEM),
          TestDataReader.getTestData(MACHINE_CLASS),
          TestDataReader.getTestData(SERIES_ID),
          TestDataReader.getTestData(MACHINE_TYPE),
          TestDataReader.getTestData(NUMBER_OF_GPUS),
          TestDataReader.getTestData(TYPE_GPU),
          TestDataReader.getTestData(LOCAL_SSD),
          TestDataReader.getTestData(DATA_CENTER_LOCATION),
          TestDataReader.getTestData(COMMITTED_USAGE));
  }
}
```

---

### test

public class GoogleCloudTest extends CommonConditions {

```
@Test(description = "get a letter with the results of processing the request")

public void checkEmailEstimateCost() {
    new InstanceCreator();
    InstanceForm instanceForm = InstanceCreator.getDataEstimateForm();
    String verificationCalculationResultsReceivedEmail = new GoogleCloudHomePage(driver)
            .openPage()
            .fillSearchInput()
            .openCalculator()
            .activationComputeEngine()
            .fillComputeEngineForm(instanceForm)
            .pressAddToEstimate()
            .saveResultEstimate()
            .pressButtonEmailEstimate()
            .openNewTab()
            .openPage()
            .copyEmailAddress()
            .comeBackToCalculator()
            .enterEmail()
            .pressButtonSendEmail()
            .returnToPageEmail()
            .pressCheckMailButton()
            .thisComparisonResultsReceivedEmailWithDataSite();
    Assert.assertEquals(verificationCalculationResultsReceivedEmail, ProcessData.getCurrentPriceInCalculator()
            , "the data received by mail does not coincide with the data received in the calculator");
}
```

---

### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

```
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>frameworklasttask</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
        <plugins>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: You're parameterised line has: `-Dbrowser=$(browser)`, the variable requires curly braces as the rest of your line. Correct it to: `-Dbrowser=${browser}`

Comment: thanks a lot, corrected it, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: So by the looks of it, your service.class is not getting back one or more of the test.data strings thus the NPE. Have you checked that all values required for service.class is available to your Jenkins agent ?

Comment: Thank you very much kind person! Yes, you understood everything correctly, I do not receive data for processing keys from my dev.properties in the line "private static final ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle (System.getProperty (" environment "));" I have added Jenkins skin shots to my question. Please save me otherwise I'm close to going crazy :-)

Comment: P.S. 
adding the full path "src / test / resources / dev.properties" to the "environment" parameter yielded no results

Comment: I think the whole problem is in the correctness of passing my parameters from Jenkins in the build section

Comment: I think the whole problem is in the correctness of passing my parameters to Jenkins in the build section

Comment: Added an answer below and have omitted the -P command for the moment, as you have not provided a <profile> tag in any of your configuration so far, this is usually in your settings.xml, or if you have declared it in a child pom.xml. Try the changes mentioned in the answer first and see how you go

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshots above, you need to correct the following:

'**Trigger/call builds on other projects**' section

- File Name in Child Projects section you have `mvn test -P -Dbrowser=${browser} -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=${surefire.suiteXmlFiles} -Denvironment=${environment} clean test` - remove this, as this section is to declare files within sub-projects of your main project "frameworklasttask", not the maven command

Now on the next section, where you have declared the maven version '3.8.1'

- Update `clean test` to `clean test -Dbrowser=${browser} -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=${surefire.suiteXmlFiles} -Denvironment=${environment}.properties`

For the moment, I have discarded the -P part of the maven command as a  tag is missing from the configuration you have provided so far.

Comment: Thank you for helping! Sorry, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I have completed the first 2 images with Jenkins infill and build result.
(Can you tell me what kind of rope and kind of soap is most suitable for me in such a situation :-))

Comment: Updated answer above for mvn cmd to change to `-Denvironment=${environment}.properties`, lets see how you get on

Comment: Thank you for not leaving me !!! adding -Denvironment = $ {environment} .properties didn't help the same result. now I'm trying to do it like "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJWqa_zGqfU&list=PLPO0LFyCaSo26oKF4xQH-vAGXgJMb_ZIn&index=4" but so far there is no result :-(

Comment: Thank you very much for your desire to help me !!! I found the solution it cost me 4 days of my life! :-) The solution is presented below !!! If you need help, please contact! In any case, you have a huge plus in karma!

Answer (score -1):

I only found a solution like this. Nothing else in this project build configuration works !!! Proven by 4 days of searching!

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vA6q.jpg)